# How to prove this two separations of connectedness is equivalent?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces, definition

**Definition 1**$\quad$ A metric space $E$ is connected if it cannot be written as the union of two nonempty separated sets (in $E$).

**Definition 2**$\quad$ A metric space $E$ is connected if it cannot be written as the union of two nonempty disjoint open (relative to $E$) sets.

Clearly the former implies the latter. But I don't know how the latter implies the former, since "separated sets" are too general a category and can be very complicated.

Is there a *basic* proof to this? Thanks in advance!

PS: Things I know are some basic properties about closed, open, compact, perfect sets etc. in metric spaces.

Comment: Is $X$ the whole space here?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott may or may not be. I'll make an edit to clarify.

Comment: Let the separated sets be $A$ and $B$. What can you say about $\{ y : \operatorname{dist}(y,A) < \operatorname{dist}(y,b)\}$?

Comment: Are you sure about the "written as the union of two nonempty disjoint open sets" part? I suspect part of the point of the exercise is that in a metric space $X$, if $E \subset X$ is disconnected, there are two disjoint open - in $X$ - sets $U,V$ such that $U\cap E \neq \varnothing \neq V\cap E$ and $E \subset U\cup V$. With the current formulation, that interpretation is impossible, since writing $E$ as the union of two open sets requires $E$ to be open in $X$, or the "open" meaning "relatively open" (open in $E$).

Comment: @DanielFischer My apologies. You're right. Openness here means being open relative to the set $E$ itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to interpret *open* as *relatively open in* $X$, since $X$ need not be open in the space.

Suppose that $X=A\cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are non-empty and separated. Then $A\cap\operatorname{cl}B=\varnothing$, so

$$B\subseteq\operatorname{cl}_XB=X\cap\operatorname{cl}B\subseteq X\setminus A=B\;,$$

and it follows that $\operatorname{cl}_XB=B$. Thus, $B$ is relatively closed in $X$, and $A=X\setminus B$ is relatively open in $X$. A similar argument shows that $B$ is relatively open in $X$. Thus, **Definition 2** implies **Definition 1**.

Note that I did not use the fact that the space is metric: the argument works in any topological space.

Comment: Thank u so much for your answer (also your answer on my previous question). I'll take a look at it later.

Comment: @Vim: You’re very welcome.